# How can i integrate my existing chatbot to an uwp application

Tags: c#, azure, uwp, bots, botframework

How can i integrate my existing chat bot to an uwp(universal windows platform) application.I have already created a chat bot using azure bot framework now i want to integrate my bot with a uwp application and publish it to windows store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can choose direct line of web chat channel.

**For Direct line you can follow below code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="bot"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js"></script>
    <script>
      BotChat.App({
        directLine: { secret: direct_line_secret },
        user: { id: 'userid' },
        bot: { id: 'botid' },
        resize: 'detect'
      }, document.getElementById("bot"));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**For Web chat**
you can use direct embed url

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/botframework-webchat/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>
<iframe src='https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/GPPBOTDEV?s=YOUR_SECRET_HERE'></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

do let me know if you need more help

Answer (score 1):

> I have already created a chat bot using azure bot framework now i want to integrate my bot with a uwp application and publish it to windows store.

There are several ways varies depending on your application's type.

If your app is native mobile app, you can enable your UWP app to communicate with your bot using [Direct Line channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/channel-connect-directline). To use `Direct Line API`, you may refer to [Key concepts in Direct Line API 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-concepts), there're samples show how to use Direct Line API 3.0 with C# and Node.js.

Or you can simply use `Web Chat` channel. In your UWP application, you may use [Web view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/web-view) and then navigate to your web chat url with secret key of your `Web Chat`, for example:

```
<WebView Source="https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/<YOUR SECRET KEY HERE>"/>
```

For other application's types or more detailed information, you may refer to this official document: [Embed a bot in an app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-design-pattern-embed-app).